# Платёжная система epayments.com

Tags: платежи

https://www.epayments.com/
https://developers.epayments.com/
В этой платёжной системе нужно сначала пройти верификацию сайта, прошли её.
Теперь как нужно начать использовать api ?
Просто их техподдержка отвечает как-то не очень охотно, раз в день.
Решил уточнить здесь, может кто работал с этой платёжной системой?
Есть ли примеры работы с api?
И там есть e-Wallet API и Merchant API. В чём разница между ними?